# Labview - Array of fixed size to receive serial data?

Tags: arrays, labview

I am receiving 128 byte data continuously every second from serial, 
I just want to know how can I replace this data to the starting index for each iteration in my byte array?

how can I do it?

-Thanks

I created an byte array and feed my serial string output to it via string to byte array converter
[image]

Comment: Without some code to reference, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Dave_St Will this help?? I have shown screenshot of the Diagram

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. I think you wish to see the byte array data in the "Array" indicator every time new data comes in. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dave_St Exactly

Comment: @Dave_St Or maybe like when the array indicator has received 128 bytes the index should reset to 0

Comment: At the moment the incoming data will be accumulated and displayed in the `Data Received` string indicator while the loop is running. The `Array` indicator will only receive data when the loop exits, because it is outside the loop, and will only receive the data that was read from the port in the last iteration of the loop, because that's what you have wired to it. What do you want to happen differently?

Comment: @nekomatic so if to observe the data as it is received ...i will add it inside the loop . But how to make it fixed to 128 bytes and then again start at the starting index of the indicator array?

Comment: So if you have received 125 bytes and the next message that is received is `ABCDEF`, what do you want to happen? Do you want `DEF` to be written to the end of the array and then `ABC` at the start, overwriting what is already there?

Comment: @nekomatic yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement circular buffer in this way:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to see the current iteration in the Array Indicator

If so, just place the Array Indicator inside the loop

Note that the Array indicator and the wire connected to it is not the same data type, there is a convert, you can see that it's different colors (orange and blue) and there is red dot where it's connected.

But if you want to collect all the data you received you should right click on your loop output and select Indexing

You would also need to change your indicator, just delete the current one and than right click on the wire -> create -> Indicator.

Or Hirshfeld

Control SW Engineer

Comment: According to their comments on the question, the asker wants a 128-character circular buffer. I'll post that as an answer as soon as I can get some spare time in front of LabVIEW.